# vuetify table custom sort "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

i am having an issue with a custom sort implementation in vuetify.

```js
      <v-data-table
        :headers="table.headers"
        :items="table.items"
        :search="search"
        disable-pagination
        :header-props="{sortByText: 'sortiere nach...'}"
        :loading="loading"
        hide-default-footer
        :custom-sort="customSort"
        @click:row="rowClickHandler"
      />
```

This is my customSort function just for now

```js
    customSort(items, sortBy, sortDesc, locale) {
      if (!this.table.loading) {
        console.log(items)
        console.log(sortBy)
        console.log(sortDesc)
        console.log(locale)
      }
    }
```

problem is that i get a big fat
`Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"`
maybe it depends on my async data fetching with axios?

i am fetching like this in my `created()` block

```js
    async fetchUsers() {
      await axios
        .get('myApiPath')
        .then((res) => {
          this.table.items = res.data
          this.table.loading = false
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an array from your `customSort()`. I believe it has nothing to do with your async data fetching.

```js
customSort(items, sortBy, sortDesc, locale) {
  if (!this.table.loading) {
    console.log(items.map(e => e.calories));
    console.log(sortBy);
    console.log(sortDesc);
    console.log(locale);
  }

  // sort items here

  return items;
}
```

Here is a [sample implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-engelbart-hntxi?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:2425-2872) of `custom-sort()`.